# Whats the use of zero sized memblocks?

Tags: c, memory-management, c99, undefined-behavior

By the worry of my last days/weeks when I figured out that much of my code does break c99 rules, what is leading into undefined behaviour, I started explicitly reading the ISO/IEC 9899:TC3 draft paper.
Especially the Appendix "J.2 Undefined behaviour"
The most of it was logical to me why it could be hard to compile code that's breaking those rules, or at some cases I could at least think "well, I don't get it, what's the problem with that, but I 'shall' do it that way"
but there is one point...

> "A non-null pointer returned by a call to the calloc, malloc, or realloc function with a zero requested size is used to access an object (7.20.3)."

(for all who haven't read ISO/IEC 9899:TC3 "J.2 Undefined behaviour", this section just explains which cases will run into undefined behaviour).

So there are so many Questions in my head about that case.

First of all:

Why should I want to allocate a memory-block of zero size?

And when I have got such a block, what can I do with it?

With the aim of avoiding undefined behaviours, probably I don't want to access the memory its pointing to...

So I did a bit more research.... looked for some different malloc() man pages.
and found out in the Linux malloc(3) man:

> "If size is 0, then malloc() returns either NULL, or a unique pointer value that can later be successfully passed to free()."

Well the only thing this helped me with was: I got now additional questions to you and myself.
The case that function call with identical parameters under identical conditions may return different results isn't that hard to imagine, OK... but those different results mostly don't have to be tread that different.
Thats what lets me suggesting, a non-null pointer to a requested zero size block could just be a unwanted side-effect.
Does this mean

```
if ((void *ptr = malloc (0)) == NULL)
{
    /*...*/
}
```

this isn't enough?
do I have to handle *alloc calls like this?

```
if (X <= 0)
{
    if ((*ptr = malloc (X)) != NULL)
    {
        exit (*);
    }
    else
    {
        /*...*/
    }
}
else
{
    if ((*ptr = malloc (X)) == NULL)
    {
        /*...*/
    }
}
```

But even if its expected, to get such an

> "unique pointer value that can later be successfully passed to free()"

,
 how to work with it?
 I could change it around OK...
 I'm even allowed to free it (BTW does it mean I HAVE to free it as I should do with every other allocated memory too, or is it just an >you are allowed to, to don't break your code flow

what would be the difference to just make any pointer like this?

```
void *X = (void *)"1234abc";
```

I hope any one can help me with that philosophy of science or is even better as interested as I'm, in it.

Comment: "when I have got such a block, what can I do with it?" - nothing useful. You can reallocate or free it, though.

Comment: I think you might be able to use that pointer as a unique identifier.

Comment: Well but isn't it then absolutly sense less? Why even mentioning such a case? If no one ever would be expecting this case, why its not jsut called "calling *alloc with size of zero, may have undefined behaviour"?

Comment: @Lalaland: You can use it as a unique identifier *if* your implementation returns a non-null result for `malloc(0)`. If you want to be sure, use `malloc(1)` (but you still need to check for a null result).

Comment: @Who ever.... Thanks for running through all my Questions + Answer and downvote absolutly all....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many memory allocation routines have a minimum-sized allocation block which they can support, and will expand any allocation request to that minimum size.  While they could have had `malloc` check whether the size is zero and return null if it is, it was simpler and easier to have all malloc requests less than the minimum size (including those for exactly zero bytes) get padded out to the minimum size.  Since the only code which would be likely to request a zero-byte malloc would be asking for a buffer whose size was determined at runtime, and since any such code would expect to free any buffer it had asked for without regard for its size, such behavior caused no difficulty.

Another thing to consider is that if `realloc` is called on a block multiple times, it may be desirable to keep on using the same memory block if it has adequate space available.  If a block which has e.g. 256 bytes allocated to it gets sized to zero, it may be desirable to hold off for awhile on using the formerly-occupied 256 bytes for any purpose other than re-expanding that memory block.  If calling `realloc` on a memory block with a requested size of zero returns a pointer to that same block, then the system will be able to recognize a subsequent request to re-expand that block and use the formerly-occupied space to satisfy it.  If the zero-byte `realloc` returned a null pointer, a request to expand that block to a non-zero size would be indistinguishable from a request to allocate a new one.

Code which uses `realloc` (or anything `malloc` related, for that matter) will generally not have any control over memory allocation and recycling policy, but some implementations of the "malloc library" may benefit from having code which doesn't need something at the moment but will likely need it in future reallocate it to size zero rather than freeing it.  Note that while the usage pattern which is best for one library may be sub-optimal in another, code which is uses "malloc library" functions in a standards-compliant fashion should work, even if not optimally, on any machine which implements them standards-compliant fashion.  If one knows that for the next year or two a program is likely to be run on a machine with a particular allocator, it may be helpful to write the code in the way that's optimal for that allocator.  The program might have in future have to run on a machine for which its allocation pattern is no longer optimal, but if that machine is faster and has more RAM (as will likely be the case), the suboptimal performance probably won't pattern.

Comment: Ah ok, and does it give me any advantages, to realloc zero size? i.e. when the system runs low in memory it prefers using that block? And the first part you wrote is just refering to c89, isn't it? and at least, do i have or had any influence as realloc user about getting a nullpointer or such an unique pointer?

Comment: @Zaibis: As a `realloc` user you have no control over such things, and whether they would be advantageous depends upon the general allocation/tracking scheme used by `malloc`.  See edit above.

Answer (score 3):

C does not support zero-sized objects, but the argument to `malloc()` is of type `size_t`, and there's no good way to prevent a program from calling `malloc(0)`. It may not be the programmer's intent, but it's not necessarily literally `malloc(0)`; it's  more likely to be `malloc(count)`, where `count` is the result of some computation.

As for the standard permitting two different behaviors, that's simply because existing implementations (at the time the original standard was being written) did different things, and the authors wanted to avoid breaking existing code. Such code was arguably already broken, or at least non-portable, but by permitting either behavior a program that made assumptions about how `malloc(0)` behaves could continue to work *on the system for which it was written*.

If you're looking for a coherent explanation, you're not going to find one. If C were being designed from scratch today, the behavior of `malloc(0)` almost certainly would have been nailed down, one way or the other. Either that, or the behavior would have been made undefined, but making it implementation-defined means that code doesn't have to check quite as carefully that it's not passing zero to `malloc()`.

And in fact the committee's decision is documented in the [C99 Rationale](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf), section 7.20.3, pages 160-161.

It does mean that:

```
void *ptr = malloc(0);
free(ptr);
```

will work correctly; `free()` does nothing if its argument is a null pointer.

What can you do with the result of `malloc(0)`? Well, if `malloc(1024)` is successful, you can store 1024 bytes in the allocated space. You can store *no* bytes in the space allocated by `malloc(0)` -- which is exactly what you asked for.

Comment: I absoloutly agree to that what you said so far, but that isn't cracking, why the comittee didn't just say "OK, malloc(0)(or ofc malloc(count), too. Just said 0 size, to make it more clearly) can't return anymore an non-null pointer. I mean the only code, which could get broken, is code that was before going to work in invalid memory. With such isntructions the developer just should blame him self. But did I get it right, that malloc is used in other languages as c/c++ which are handling that case? (or did u mention c++ is supporting zero sized blocks?I'm not that conform with c++)

Comment: @Zaibis: `malloc` works the same way in C and C++, but C++ code normally uses `new` instead. Prior to the C standard, there were C implementations where `malloc(0)` would return a unique non-null pointer, and presumably there were programs that depended on that behavior; for example, such pointers are unique, which could be useful. Those implementations could continue to work the same way, and programs that depended on that behavior could continue to work *on those implementations*. I'm not convinced that the committee made the best decision; I'm sure political compromise was involved.

Comment: @KeithThompson: If there were nothing but `malloc` and `free`, zero-byte allocations probably wouldn't make any sense, but there's also `realloc` to consider.  If a buffer gets resized repeatedly, and the requested size is sometimes zero, the system shouldn't be overly eager to give away the memory immediately following a shrunken buffer to anything other than its former owner, but if `realloc` with a size of zero returns null, the former owner of the buffer will have no way to ask for it back.

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be more explicit, as in:

```
if (X <= 0)
{
    ptr = NULL;
}
else
{
    ptr = malloc(X);
    if (ptr == NULL)
    {
        /*...*/
    }
}
```

and this can be distilled to:

```
 ptr = (X <= 0) ? NULL : malloc(X);
 if (ptr == NULL) { /* ... */}
```

Today, in C, if `malloc` cannot acquire the requested storage it returns NULL.  Also, this code completely avoids the question and more importantly avoids a potential pitfall.

Comment: The first snippet you mentioned just was my example of avoidng the non-nullpointer case. And As you can see in the linux man page for malloc there is it CAN return stil nonNULL pointer if requesting zero sized storage.

Comment: @Zaibis, my point is why do something that is unusual and requires the next programmer to research and figure out that it works, when you can avoid the whole issue.

Comment: HAHA! Yeah of course. I will avoid this case. I even never was going to think about using it. But you know, I want to write clean c code, and want to learn and respect the standard to 100% as far I'm able to. And just using rules. is a hard way of it, if u know why the rules are as they are, its much easier. and i don't want anyone to research it for me, if he isn't that interested in it, as I'm. You know, this is not a "My code isn't working, plz help me as fast as you can"-problem, this is a knowledge-problem and I'm just interested in it.

Comment: @Zaibis, I was referring to the workplace not StackOverflow!  When you get a job writing code or maintaining code then you become aware of the cost of code that uses obscure language features, especially when the same thing could have been done more directly.